# Javascript AutoLinker

Tags: javascript, dependency-injection

I am coming from the C++ world where I am used to having an auto-linker in Visual Studio for example. This manages all of my dependencies and ensures that all the dependencies that I need are bundled with my main code, however, it also strips out all of those which aren't referenced. It strikes me that this would be **really** useful with Javascript, especially when you start getting into things like Google Polymer, when all of a sudden you can have hundreds of file in your dependencies.

I am using Grunt with the SailsJS which copies all of the files defined in my pipeline file, e.g.

```
var jsFilesToInject = [
  'js/dependencies/sails.io.js',
  'bower_components/**/*.js',
  'js/dependencies/**/*.js',

];
```

Is there anything which can create the auto-linker functionality as in C/C++, or is there any reason why a tool like this doesn't exist (language constraints etc.)